# IntelliJ is not recognizing Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Project in which I am using Maven to manage my dependencies. I have some (5 to 10) packages mentioned inside the POM-File and Maven is successfully downloading them into my local repository.

But IntelliJ is not recognizing these packages. Not even the SpringBoot-Packages.

I have tried different things:

- Delete local Maven-Repository
- Create a new Project inside IntelliJ from existing Sources but with the same Directory as the original Project
- Create a new Project inside IntelliJ from existing Sources but I have copied the `src`-Folder and the POM-File to a new Directory first

Why is IntelliJ not recognizing the Maven-Dependencies?

P.S.: The Maven-Build is successful. So Maven IS recognizing the packages inside the repository.

Comment: Are you using any proxy? Are these dependencies related to any "corporate repository"? IntelliJ by default uses its default embedded Maven, its settings could differ to your "maven prompt". Could you show an error screen or something about the IntellJ error please?

Comment: Yes, I am using a proxy which is set inside the Settings.xml. The dependencies are placed inside a corporate repository or lets say a local nexus. IntelliJ doesnt prompt an error for downloading the dependencies but shows errors for the used classes not to be found.

Comment: @sigur this is an example error here `java: package org.aspectj.lang does not exist`

Comment: If I am in your case I should go for these: which settings.xml and local repository is using IntelliJ Maven (Go to Settings and look for Tools > Maven) and then execute an Invalidate Caches and Restart of IntelliJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ seems to handle an Index for all dependencies inside the project. And this Index was not correctly handled in my case by IntelliJ.

But I found out that I can manually clear this cache/index by using following function:

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Comment: so annoying that Intellij is not able to fix it

Answer (score 3):

In case that the problem still exists after `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` (as suggested by @Snickbrack), reload the maven projects by `Maven > Reload all maven projects`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. **Right click** on **pom.xml -> maven-> Reload Project,** Resolved my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34503592)

Comment: Invalidating the cache didn't work, but your solution did!

Answer (score 2):

Please run the command `mvn idea:idea` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just open maven pom.xml as project instead of creating new project from sources

Comment: How can I open the project with only a POM-File? Why are you not showing the process here?

Comment: File -> Open -> select pom.xml  ->  confirm "open as project"

Comment: I did this but it shows the same errors as the packages are not recognized...

Comment: Environment variables like M2_HOME are set?

Comment: Variables JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME are set, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the maven home path by following the steps below:

1. Select the project in Project window >> File >> settings>> Build,Execution,Deployment >> Maven
2. Check the 'Maven home path' as per Maven installation location. It will download all the dependencies.

Answer (score -3):

Right click on pom.xml Maven -> Reload project